# Meta Insights - API/SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to pull the metrics as seen in the attached image into my own app through FB's API. I don't see any of these as being available through the Insights API though. Can someone guide me as to how I can programmatically retrieve this data?

[Metrics to pull](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsQBl.png)

FB API considered: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/breakdowns

Comment: The Page Insights API is your best for any metric that is exposed via the API. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v16.0/insights You will probably not get all of those insights in the image via the API though.

Comment: The docs that you have linked for insights are for [Marketing (Ads) API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-apis/) which is for Ads objects and not necessarily pages.